# Prove that F $\in$B(X,Y)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a problem I need to solve and I'll send it as I have it in my book and then explain what I can (I'm not from a mathematical background.)

"Prove that F $\in$ BL(X,Y), where (X, $\parallel . \parallel$) and (Y, $\parallel . \parallel$) are normed spaces. it has the property that dim(X) is finite or dim(Y) is finite, then F $\in$ C(X,Y)".

Now, I know I have two vectors spaces and I somehow have to link this to the property of the dim and the fact that it is finite.
If you have any advice, suggestion or topic you know, please tell me, I don't want to have the problem solved for me.

Comment: A linear map between finite dimensional linear spaces is automatically continuous...

Comment: Assuming BL means bounded linear operator and $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces then you don't need dimension. Suppose $(x_n) \subseteq X$ is such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. Then $\|F(x_n) - F(x)\| = \|F(x_n - x)\| \leq M \|x_n - x\| \rightarrow 0$ so $F(x_n) \rightarrow F(x)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator)